# Mac Mini upgraded to Mountain Lion can't connect to WiFi network

Tags: wireless-networking, osx-mountain-lion

I have a Mac Mini and just upgraded it to Mountain Lion. It always displays the following:

[image]

I tried to follow the instructions on the following page, but it didn't help: [Fix OS X Mountain Lion Wireless Connection Problems](http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/02/fix-os-x-mountain-lion-wireless-connection-problems/)

Comment: What was the part about your iPhone? Isn't it able to connect to the WiFi router either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your system have a "Profiles" preference pane? If so delete any profiles that are in there and it should disappear. Then you should be able to connect to a Wi-FI network again.